# Example of a vector that is a generalised eigenvector but not an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1&  1\\ 0 &  1&  1\\ 0&  0&  1\end{pmatrix}$, a $3\times 3$ matrix.

A generalised eigenvector of $A$ is a non-zero vector $v$, an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that
$[(A-bI)^k] v = 0$, for some scalar $b$ and some integer $k\geqslant 1$

Give an example of a vector $v$, element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that $v$ is a generalised eigenvector of $A$ but not an eigenvector of $A$.

I am not too sure how to find the generalised eigenvectors.

I started by $\det(A-bI)^k = k^3 \det(A-bI) = 0$

$\implies \det(A-bI) = 0$ to find eigenvalues for the generalised eigenvectors, but I realized won't this just be the same as finding eigenvectors?? 
Can someone please tell me what I did wrong or how I should do it

Thanks

Comment: is 1 1 1  the column entries or row entries?

Comment: 1 1 1 is the first row entries

Comment: Please check my edit to see how to typeset a matrix.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is clearly **not** an eigenvector (please do check it).

However, since $(A - I)^{3} = 0$ (please do check it!), **all nonzero vectors are generalised eigenvectors** with respect to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Why isn't it an eigenvector? I multiplied it by A and got itself again.

Comment: @Howard, sorry, you're perfectly right, it's just that I am used to ***row*** vectors... it's fixed now. Again, my apologies.

Comment: Oh right, makes sense to me now, thanks a lot

Comment: @Howard, please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if you found it useful.